# adding to column in case expression?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've tried to find an answer everywhere, but can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to add to a column of a row when certain terms are met, and then have it display the results. Like,

```
select itemName
case demand when 'high' then price + 2
            when 'low' then price - 1
            else price
from itemTable
```

Assuming the data was something like:

```
Item1 | high | 2
```

the output would be:

```
Item1 | 4
```

This is in Oracle SQL Developer, and I've tried using a select statement inside of the `then`, but a subquery seems a little over the top for something like this.

Comment: select itemName,
    (case demand when 'high' then price + 2
                when 'low' then price - 1
                else price end) as somethingelse
    from itemTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a comma to separate the two column definitions, and to give a name to the computed column;

```
select 
    itemName,    
    case demand 
        when 'high' then price + 2
        when 'low' then price - 1
        else price
    end AS demand
from itemTable
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized my problem was case sensitivity. The actual data was `'HIGH'` instead of `'high'`.